# magento show free shipping text

Tags: php, magento

I want to show the freeshipping price as text, like "Free shipping" but I can't get it to work. In app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php I found these lines:

```
$method->setPrice('0.00');
$method->setCost('0.00');
```

But if I change the 0.00 to "Free shipping", nothing happens.
I did a LOT of research on the internet but nothing works. There are also much plugins that can set the price to "Free" but that only counts for the products.

So I am desperate and I hope someone can help me here.
I am using Magento 1.7.0.2.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml` to the respective theme folder you are using.
2. In the `available.phtml` file, look for the following code (around line 56):

   ```
   <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $_rate->getMethodTitle() ?>
   <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
   <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
   <?php echo $_excl; ?>
   <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
       (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
   <?php endif; ?>
   </label>
   ```
3. Replace it with the following:

   ```
   <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $_rate->getMethodTitle() ?>
   <?php if($_rate->getPrice() > 0) : ?>        
   <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
   <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
   <?php echo $_excl; ?>
   <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
       (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php else : ?>
         (<?php echo $this->__('Free Shipping'); ?>)
   <?php endif; ?>
   </label>
   ```
4. Save `available.phtml`, and clear your Magento caches.  "Free Shipping" will now appear next to all methods containing a $0 amount on the One-Page-Checkout shipping section.

Comment: That works great for the checkout page, thanks!
But if I calculate the shipping price with the estimate shipping and tax box, then it still shows 0.00. So which file should I edit to do the same for that box? Thanks again!

Comment: The file for the calculate shipping block is `app/design/frontend/[theme_path]/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`.  For future reference, you can determine the exact template paths loaded on the frontend by enabling `Template Path Hints` in the Magento configuration.  You can find a quick tutorial on how to do this here: https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21255937-How-do-I-turn-on-template-path-hints-

Comment: You are a great helper! Thanks a lot